# Identify varying consecutive multiples in a sorted list

Tags: python

I have a sorted list and would like to identify consecutive multiple numbers in that list. The list can contain consecutive multiples of different order, which makes it more difficult.

Some test cases:

```
[1,3,4,5] -> [[1], [3,4,5]]
[1,3,5,6,7] -> [[1], [3], [5,6,7]]
# consecutive multiples of 1 and 2 (or n)
[1,2,3,7,9,11] -> [[1,2,3], [7,9,11]
[1,2,3,7,10,12,14,25] -> [[1,2,3], [7], [10,12,14], [25]]
# overlapping consecutives !!!
[1,2,3,4,6,8,10] -> [[1,2,3,4], [6,8,10]
```

Now, I have no idea what I'm doing. What I have done is to group pairwise by the distance between numbers, which was a good start, but then I am having a lot of issues identifying which element in each pair goes where, i.e.

```
 # initial list    
 [1,3,4,5]
 # pairs of same distance
 [[1,3], [[3,4], [4,5]]
 # algo to get the final result ?
 [[1], [3,4,5]]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Maybe mentioning what I want this for would make it more clear.

I want to transform something like:

```
[1,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,20,22,24,26,28,30]
```

into

```
1, 5, 10 to 15 by 1, 17, 20 to 30 by 2
```

Comment: In `[1,3,4,5] -> [[1], [3,4,5]]` why is the output `[[1], [3,4,5]]` and not `[[1,3], [4,5]]`? Should we choose to split to maximize the lengths of the sub-slices?

Comment: Why on earth you want: `[1,3,5,6,7] -> [[1], [3], [5,6,7]]` instead of `[[1,3], [5,6,7]]` as a result? Can you explain the logic after your expected outputs? I cannot see any *multiple*, besides that any natural number is a multiple of 1, so it doesn't make any sense your comment about "multiples of 1 and 2". It seems like you are looking at *the difference* between consecutive numbers, but then I can't understand some of your results.

Comment: Or even: `[[1, 3, 5], [6, 7]]`

Comment: I am indeed trying to split to maximize the lengths of the sub-slices.

Comment: @Cricri Then the examples you made are wrong. Please correct them and clarify what you want to do in your question.

Comment: I want to present a selection in a more user friendly way. Let's say the user selects: 1, 3,4,5,6,7, 10,12,14,16,... I want that as 1, 3 to 7 by 1, 10 to 16 by 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that incorporates @Bakuriu's optimization:

```
MINIMAL_MATCH = 3

def find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness(data):
    """
    >>> find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness([1,3,4,5])
    [[1], [3, 4, 5]]
    >>> find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness([1,3,5,6,7])
    [[1, 3, 5], [6], [7]]
    >>> find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness([1,2,3,7,9,11])
    [[1, 2, 3], [7, 9, 11]]
    >>> find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness([1,2,3,7,10,12,14,25])
    [[1, 2, 3], [7], [10, 12, 14], [25]]
    >>> find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness([1,2,3,4,6,8,10])
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 8, 10]]
    >>> find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness([1,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,20,22,24,26,28,30])
    [[1], [5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [17], [20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]]
    """
    def pair_iter(series):
        from itertools import tee
        _first, _next = tee(series)
        next(_next, None)
        for i, (f, n) in enumerate(zip(_first, _next), start=MINIMAL_MATCH - 1):
            yield i, f, n

    result = []
    while len(data) >= MINIMAL_MATCH:
        test = data[1] - data[0]
        if (data[2] - data[1]) == test:
            for i, f, n in pair_iter(data):
                if (n - f) != test:
                    i -= 1
                    break
        else:
            i = 1
        data, match = data[i:], data[:i]
        result.append(match)
    for d in data:
        result.append([d])
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from doctest import testmod
    testmod()
```

It handles all your current test cases. Give me new failing test cases if you have any.

As mentioned in comments below, I am assuming that the shortest sequence is now three elements since a sequence of two is trivial.

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html for an explanation of the pairwise iterator.

Comment: He basically wants to group by difference with the contiguous elements... however it's not clear how to handle ambiguous situations where a number could be grouped both with its left neighbour or its right neighbour.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Presumably, then, the minimum size of a group should be 3. Otherwise, it is trivial to have groups of 2.

Comment: @hughdbrown thanks for the input. My data can have not only multiples of 1, but multiples of two, or three, or n. The code you submitted only expects mutliples of 1 in the input.

Comment: >>> find_consecutive([1,3,5,6,7,11,13,15])
    [[1], [3], [5, 6, 7], [11, 13, 15]]
    >>> find_consecutive([1,3,5,6,7,9,11,13])
    [[1], [3], [5, 6, 7], [9,11,13]]

Comment: @hughdbrown The following is failing: find_some_sort_of_weird_consecutiveness([1,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,20,22,24,26,28,30]) where I expect: [[1], [5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [17], [20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]]

Comment: @Cricri: tweaked to handle this case. Passes tests on all sample data so far.

Comment: You can avoid to use `step_test`. At the beginning of the `while` you can create `d = {data[1] - data[0]}` then in the loop you can do: `d.add(data[i-1] - data[i-2]); if len(d) > 1: i = 1 if i == 3 else i - 1` etc. It gets immediately quite faster since it avoids recreating the `set` everytime you have an element in the group.

Comment: Looks like the right solution, still digesting it. Great code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start out with a difference list.

```
length_a = len(list1)
diff_v  = [list1[j+1] - list1[j] for j in range(length_a-1)]
```

so [1,2,3,7,11,13,15,17] becomes [1,1,4,4,2,2,2]

now it is easy

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep track of your last output value as you go along:

```
in_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
out = [[in[0]]]
for item in in_[1:]:
    if out[-1][-1] != item - 1:
        out.append([])
    out[-1].append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would group the list by its difference between index and value:

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = [1,3,4,5]
result = []
for key, group in groupby(enumerate(lst), key = lambda (i, value): value - i):
    result.append([value for i, value in group])
print result
[[1], [3, 4, 5]]
```

*What did I do?*

```
# at first I enumerate every item of list:
print list(enumerate(lst))
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)]

# Then I subtract the index of each item from the item itself:
print [ value - i for i, value in enumerate(lst)]
[1, 2, 2, 2]

# As you see, consecutive numbers turn out to have the same difference between index and value
# We can use this feature and group the list by the difference of value minus index
print list( groupby(enumerate(lst), key = lambda (i, value): value - i) )
[(1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x104bff050>), (2, <itertools._grouper object at 0x104bff410>)]

# Now you can see how it works. Now I just want to add how to write this in one logical line:
result = [ [value for i, value in group]
    for key, group in groupby(enumerate(lst), key = lambda (i, value): value - i)]
print result
[[1], [3, 4, 5]]
```

## Approach for identifying consecutive multiples of n

Let's have a look at this list,

```
lst = [1,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,21,24,26,28,30]
```

especially at the differences between neighbor elements and the differences of differences of three consecutive elements:

```
  1,   5,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  17,  21,  24,  26,  28,  30
     4,   5,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   2,   4,   3,   2,   2,   2
       1,  -4,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   2,  -1,  -1,   0,   0
```

We see, that there are zeros in the third row, whenever there are connective multiples in the first row. If we think of it mathematically, the 2nd derivative of a functions's linear sections is also zero. So lets use this property...

The "2nd derivative" of  a list `lst` can be calculated like this

```
lst[i+2]-2*lst[i+1]+lst[i]
```

Note that this definition of the second order difference "looks" two indexes ahead.
Now here is the code detecting the consecutive multiples:

```
from itertools import groupby
# We have to keep track of the  indexes in the list, that have already been used
available_indexes = set(range(len(lst)))
for second_order_diff, grouper in groupby(range(len(lst)-2), key = lambda i: lst[i+2]-2*lst[i+1]+lst[i]):
    # store all not-consumed indexes in a list
    grp_indexes = [i for i in grouper if i in available_indexes]

    if grp_indexes  and second_order_diff == 0:
        # There are consecutive multiples
        min_index, max_index = grp_indexes[0], grp_indexes[-1] + 2
        print "Group from ", lst[min_index], "to", lst[max_index], "by", lst[min_index+1]-lst[min_index]
        available_indexes -= set(range(min_index, max_index+1))
    else:
        # The not "consumed" indexes in this group are not consecutive
        for i in grp_indexes:
            print lst[i]
            available_indexes.discard(i)
# The last two elements could be lost without the following two lines
for i in sorted(available_indexes):
    print lst[i]
```

**Output:**

```
1
5
Group from  10 to 15 by 1
17
21
Group from  24 to 30 by 2
```

Comment: This only works for consecutive (multiples of 1) numbers. In my case I can have multiples of 2 (or n) as well (e.g. [1,4,6,8]).

Comment: @Cricri: It  has been a while, but now I found a new approach.

Comment: That's a nice solution. It still does not work for cases like `[1,3,5,6,7]` where I would expect `[[1, 3, 5], [6], [7]]` rather than `[[1, 3, 5], [5, 6, 7]]`. I guess that could easily be fixed by checking also if the min_index and max_index have not been used yet (i.e. `in available_indexes`).

Comment: @Cricri Ok, I fixed that by taking only available indexes in `group_indexes`... Thanks you brought up this problem...